# Problem with android MediaRecorder setVideoSize()

Tags: android, mediarecorder

Can android `MediaRecorder` capture video with resolution higher than `320*240`?

When I used `MediaRecorder::setVideoSize()` to set the video size, the captured video were all at the resolution of `320*240`. Whats even worse, the higher ones can not get a clear video, they were somehow greenish. (encoder used is `h263`, format is `mpeg4`)

Android version used here is `1.6`

Could you please anyone help me out?

Answer (score 9):

I had an issue similar to what is described here. I turned out that I had to restructure my code slightly before I could adjust the video size.

The important thing is that setVideoSize() is called before setVideoEncoder(). I can't find this in the documentation, however it solved my problems with setting a specific video resolution.
Also keep in mind that setOutputFormat() should be called before setVideoSize().

As as side note the same is true for setVideoFrameRate(). If it is not called before setVideoEncoder() it will not have any affect.

This was tested with Android 2.3.3

Here is a code example:

```
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
recorder.setVideoSize(640,480);
recorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: This gives me the error `E/MediaRecorder﹕ start failed: -19`.

Comment: Its work very good! Дуже дякую +1!

Answer (score 3):

First you are going to want to determine what your Camera supports. Try:

```
            List<String> anti = params.getSupportedAntibanding(); 
    List<String> color = params.getSupportedColorEffects();
    List<String> focus = params.getSupportedFocusModes(); 
    List<String> flash = params.getSupportedFlashModes();
    List<Size> previewSize = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    List<Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
    List<Integer> frameRates = params.getSupportedPreviewFrameRates();
    List<Integer> pictureFormats = params.getSupportedPictureFormats();
    List<String> scene = params.getSupportedSceneModes(); 
    List<String> white = params.getSupportedWhiteBalance();
```

This will tell you all of the Camera's supported parameters. Second Make sure that you initialize your MediaRecorder properly see the google documentation for the order in which you need to set the MediaRecorder. Also, if your Camera.setPreviewSize and MediaRecorder.setVideoSize are different it can cause odd behavior.

Comment: i just hope they would write it (about VideoSize and PreviewSize) on their API documentation.

Comment: isn't setVideoSize() just calls setPreviewSize()? Meaning, they will still have the same value in the end as long as the videosize is one of the supported preview sizes.

Comment: params is an instance of Camera.Parameters (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html), accessed by calling camera.getParameters()