# How to capture a desired resolution video?

Tags: android, camera

When I am using this code.For 8mp camera with SOME_VALUE=0 : video quality is higher then 2mp camera with SOME_VALUE=10

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, SOME_VALUE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURED);
```

So how can I make some consistency in video quality(like set resolutions) for any device using code?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve it by using

```
mVideoRecorder.setVideoSize(640, 480);
```

For more detail refer the following likns

1. [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032912/android-does-anyone-know-how-to-capture-video/7628939#7628939)
2. [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032912/android-does-anyone-know-how-to-capture-video/1592917#1592917)
3. [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988712/problem-with-android-mediarecorder-setvideosize/8009482#8009482)
4. [Link 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980996/camera-intent-with-resolution-parameters-in-android/7981338#7981338)

Thanks.